# pgsql replication - how sync after master down

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave

ive run postgres on 1 slave server and sync data between 1master and 1 slave.

question is what happen when master get down? data will write on slave? ( is write methos enable by default on slave or i have to do something? )
after 1 hour when master get up, during this downtime new data have write on slave, how upate master for new data?

also this is my current master postgres.conf :

```
wal_level = replica 
synchronous_commit = on
synchronous_standby_names = '*'
```

is it ok?

Comment: There is no built-in automatic failover. You will need something to handle routing/IP changes for your applications too. I recommend reading the manuals about how replication works and then searching the internet for "patroni" "repmgr" "high availability" and other related terms

Comment: there is a way, check this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby-failover.html

Comment: There is nothing built into PostgreSQL to manage automatic failover. You have to use a third-party tool like Patroni.

Comment: you mean postg doesnt have any fail-over built n function? so master-slave is just for backup ?